# Can't run jScrollPane! please help?

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrollbar, jscrollpane

Hi i've been trying jScrollPane and its not running for some weird reason. 
Heres the link to the code i didnt know how to include the jScrollPane scripts and all in jsfiddle,so if anyone could do that,it'd be great! Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/ithril/S8dzb/

Comment: This question can no longer be edited unless the code is added to the question. Since that's a lot of work for such a brief post, I am voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/S8dzb/6).
You have to have a html element bigger than the container. the solution: wrap the text into another element.

Comment: Thanks a lot,mate! Actually i realised i was also placing the javascript wrong. It should have been placed after the content div. Thanks man!